# Show an equation give a holomorphic function on the upper half plane

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}_+\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be the upper half plane,and $\bar{\mathbb{H}}_+=\mathbb{H}_+\cup \mathbb{R}$. Then consider the following equation:
$$z=-\frac{1}{m}-m+\frac{a^2}{ca^2m+1}.$$

Show that for each fixed $a,c\in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $z\in \mathbb{H}_+$, there is a unique $m=m(z)\in \mathbb{H}_+$ and it has a continuous continuation to $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$. Show also that $m$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{H}_+$ and if $m$ is considered as a function of $z,a,c\in \bar{\mathbb{H}}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+$, then it is continuous.

My attempt: if the equation is $z=-\frac{1}{m}-m$ or $z=-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{a^2}{ca^2m+1}$, then there is a well-known method using the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{H}_+$ and the Banach fixed point theorem to solve this problem. But in this problem it's much harder for me to show $f(m)=(-z-m+\frac{a^2}{ca^2m+1})^{-1}$ is a contraction mapping. So I want to ask in this problem can we still use the Banach fixed point theorem to solve this problem? Or are there any other ways?

Any help is appreciated.